# reading string from socket error-connection reset error

Tags: java, sockets

```
java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(is));

String cmd=null;
while(is.available()<1){}
cmd = br.readLine();

System.out.println("cmd: "+cmd);

if(cmd.equals("search")){

    String[] param = br.readLine().split(",");

    for(String s:param){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

this the client code which accepts a string sent by server.but an exception is thrown in the line `cmd=br.readLine()...` a connection reset error..

server code is

```
Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),1234);
OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();InputStream is=s.getInputStream();
java.io.BufferedWriter bw=new java.io.BufferedWriter(new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(os)); 
String ss="search";
bw.println(ss);
bw.flush();
System.out.println("search cmded");        

String param = "a,*,0,-1";
bw.println(param);
bw.flush();
System.out.println("param sent");
```

i've tried using print writer and the bufferedwriter but nothing is working correctly
so what could be the possible solution ???

also one thing worth mentioning is im using a listener service which creates a new server code mentioned above to handle particular client requests...
so wot could be soln now ??

Answer (score 0):

In the server, your `BufferedWriter` is named `bw` but you're writing to `pw`.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake...its bw not pw ;so whats the problem ??

Comment: Given the typo, how do we know there aren't more typos, and that the code in your post is actually what you are executing?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the available() test. You have it back to front, and it's not valid anyway. readLine() will block while there is no data. Just test the return value of readLine() for null, and break.

Comment: thanx for the advice EJP but it still aint working..whenver the control gets to the br.readline(), connection reset exception is thrown

Comment: What's the meaning of the first line of server code? Where is the accept() call?